# Runtime error when running Jasper (Pocketsphinx) - cannot find hidden markov model

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, speech-to-text, hidden-markov-models, pocketsphinx

I have a raspberry pi 3 and I am trying to run Jasper client for offline sppech to text recognition.

I have followed installation instructions from here:
http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/
Method 3: Manual Installation then Install Jasper, then  Install dependencies for PocketSphinx STT engine, then Install Dependencies for SVOX Pico TTS engine.

After doing the above i moved to Configuration: http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/configuration/

I've got the issue here when configuring the Pocketsphinx STT engine. Instructions say:
"Install the required software. Then, locate your FST model (g014b2b.fst) and your Hidden Markov Model directory (hub4wsj_sc_8k). If the paths below are incorrect, add the correct paths to your profile.yml:

```
stt_engine: sphinx
pocketsphinx:
  fst_model: '../phonetisaurus/g014b2b.fst'                                       #optional
  hmm_dir: '/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k' #optional"
```

I cannot find hmm directory neither here or in any other location
    /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k

fst model could be found though.

So when attempting to run Jasper, I get the following error:

```
**ERROR:client.stt:hmm_dir '/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US     /hub4wsj_sc_8k' does not exist! Please make sure that you have set the correct   hmm_dir in your profile.
ERROR:root:Error occured!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "jasper.py", line 146, in
app = Jasper()
File "jasper.py", line 109, in init
stt_passive_engine_class.get_passive_instance(),
File "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py", line 48, in get_passive_instance
return cls.get_instance('keyword', phrases)
File "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py", line 42, in get_instance
instance = cls(**config)
File "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py", line 105, in init
raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: hmm_dir '/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US   /hub4wsj_sc_8k' does not exist! Please make sure that you have set the correct hmm_dir in your profile**
```

Does anyone know why hidden markov model directory is missing and how to get it installed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check below path for acoustic model.

```
/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us
```

Or alternativly you can download following acoustic model and use it with Jasper

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/cmusphinx-en-us-ptm-5.2.tar.gz/download
```

Comment: Thanks. I did the first one. Now I am getting the following error:

Comment: ERROR:root:Error occured!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jasper.py", line 146, in <module>
    app = Jasper()
  File "jasper.py", line 109, in __init__
    stt_passive_engine_class.get_passive_instance(),
  File "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py", line 48, in get_passive_instance
    return cls.get_instance('keyword', phrases)
  File "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py", line 42, in get_instance
    instance = cls(**config)
  File "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py", line 126, in __init__
    **vocabulary.decoder_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hmm

Comment: which pocketsphinx version did you install ? try pocketsphinx 0.8 if you are using jasper-master version.

Comment: Hi, yes, 0.8...apparently I made a mistake when specifying installation path for one of the programs. I've decided to start all over with the installation process. Hopefully goes well this time...Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
/home/pi/sphinxbase-0.8/pocketsphinx-0.8/model/hmm/en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k
```